# Export plot as pdf with a utf8 character

Tags: r, pdf, graphics, utf-8, sweave

The utf8 character in the label does not appear when I save the plot in pdf format. It does not appear when I use the "Export" button in RStudio, and it does not appear when I include this code in a Sweave document with pdf graphics output. My problem is to get the correct pdf output with Sweave (not knitr). 
(If I don't find a solution, I will generate it with `tikzDevice`)

```
ylab <- expression(paste("", bar(italic("\u2113")), "(",phi[0], "|", italic(list(x,y)), ")"))
plot(0,0, ylab=ylab)
```

Comment: Try `CairoPDF()` from the `Cairo` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

[Follow up question: custom graphical device in sweave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221471/custom-graphical-device-in-sweave) shows how to integrate this into a custom graphic device.

---

This seems to render  using `CairoPDF()` frm the `Cairo` package using ubuntu14.04, R3.2.1.**EDIT** from Stephane in the comments: if `CairoPDF()` doesn't work, then try `cairo_pdf()`.

Some sweave code (using Rstudio)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<Export_plot, echo=FALSE>>=
library(Cairo)

CairoPDF("test.pdf")
par(mar=c(6,6,6,6))
ylab <- expression(paste("", bar(italic("\u2113")), "(",phi[0], "|", italic(list(x,y)), ")"))
plot(0,0, ylab=ylab, cex.lab=2)
invisible(dev.off())

@

%Plot
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{test.pdf}

\end{document}
```

This is the pdf output i get (note the resolution is rubbish as i have converted it to png via gimp)

[image]

Comment: I'm under Ubuntu 14.04, R 3.1.3, and this doesn't work (I get like a minus sign instead of "ell"), even in the console (outside Sweave)

Comment: strange .. i get an ell bar ? ill post an image

Comment: Finally it works when I replace `CairoPDF` with `cairo_pdf`.

Comment: Maybe you could propose `cairo_pdf` as an alternative in your answer so that I check the mark to accept it.

Comment: Thats great you found a solution Stephane ... i have edited the answer. Mayve it is something to do with the tex version why `CairoPDF` doesnt work ??? but nvm