# How to print plus-minus and beta signs in bquote, and correctly export to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, symbols

¿How do you print the ± sign in a bquote() expression in R?

I have tried the following:

```
pm
%pm%
±
```

These have not worked.

---

UPDATE #1 Here is some sample code

```
plot(NULL,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10),xlab=NA,ylab=NA,xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
c <- "name"
p <- .004
n <- 969
b <- 1.23
s <- 0.45
tmp.txt <- paste(c(c," (n=",n,")\nslope = ",b,"±",s,"\n",ifelse(p==0,"p<.001",paste0("p=",p))),collapse="")
text(9.5,9.5,labels=tmp.txt,adj=c(1,1),cex=.75)
```

What I am trying to do is to make the 2nd line have beta (the symbol) instead of slope, and the ± symbol to appear.  If I use expression, I can get the beta, but not the ±; if I just paste in ß (or something similar), it won't run.

---

UPDATE #2: It appears I *HAVE* to use bquote()...else the beta character won't print when piped out via pdf().

Comment: [`?plotmath`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) suggests `x %+-% y`.

Comment: this did not work in the bquote()...¿does plotmath() go inside the bquote()? (the documentation on this function in R help is abysmal)

Comment: update to last comment:  there is no plotmath() function in R, so I'm even more at a loss how to proceed to solve this

Comment: If you type `?plotmath` in your R console, you will get a help page listing different math annotations you can use in `bquote()`. Use `%+-%` inside your `bquote()` call.

Comment: according to the R help:
"Control characters (e.g., \n) are not interpreted in character strings in plotmath, unlike normal plotting."
So I'm wondering if this request is impossible in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302367/concatenate-strings-and-expressions-in-a-plots-title) suggests using `paste` with `bquote`. You could then use the Unicode character of ±:

```
x <- 232323
plot(1:10, main = bquote(paste(ARL[1], " curve for ", S^2, "; x=\U00B1",.(x))))
```

Note that this example (minus the  inclusion of \U00B1) came from fabian's answer to the previously linked question.

Comment: I am trying to get the bquote() text to appear on the middle line...and I cannot figure out a was to use the paste() function to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you have to use `bquote`? Given your update, does `tmp.txt <- paste(c(c," (n=",n,")\n\U03B2 = ",b,"±",s,"\n",ifelse(p==0,"p<.001",paste0("p=",p))),collapse="")` solve your problem?

Comment: yes, this worked...now here's to hoping I never have to ever use bquote()...thnx

Comment: update...this did NOT work...it displayed correctly inside of R, but when piping the graphic to a file with pdf(), it won't plot the beta

Comment: How are you piping the plot? When I use `pdf("plot.pdf")`, it works on my machine.

Comment: pdf(file="tmp_plot_02a.pdf",width=6.5,height=4.5)

Comment: My bad, change to `tmp.txt <- paste(c(c," (n=",n,")\n\U03B2 = ",b,"\U00B1",s,"\n",ifelse(p==0,"p<.001",paste0("p=",p))),collapse="")`. You need the unicode character of the plus-minus sign.

Comment: thnx, but the problem was with the beta not printing in the *.pdf (the ± prints fine either way)

Comment: The only other reason I can think of that it would work on my machine and not yours is due to the default encoding. A work-around might be to use `cairo_pdf` (or `cairoPDF`) instead of `pdf` as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075826/export-plot-as-pdf-with-a-utf8-character. If that doesn't work, I'm not sure what else I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the advice given, but it didn't fully accomplish my goal.  Here is the workaround I came up with (and I personally think it is just short of asinine...but I'm at a loss).

```
    c <- "name"
    p <- .004
    n <- 969
    b <- 1.23
    s <- 0.45

    ## draw empty plot
    plot(NULL,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10),xlab=NA,ylab=NA,xaxs="i",yaxs="i")

    ## place the "poor man's substitute"
    tmp.txt <- paste(c(c," (n=",n,")\nslope = ",b,"±",s,"\n",ifelse(p==0,"p<.001",paste0("p=",p))),collapse="")
    text(9.5,9.5,labels=tmp.txt,adj=c(1,1),cex=.75)

    ## place the next best option
    tmp.txt <- paste(c(c," (n=",n,")\n\U03B2  = ",b,"±",s,"\n",ifelse(p==0,"p<.001",paste0("p=",p))),collapse="")
    text(9.5,7.5,labels=tmp.txt,adj=c(1,1),cex=.75)

    ## place the two boxes to superimpose the bquote() version
    tmp.txt2 <- paste(c(c," (n=",n,")\n\n",ifelse(p==0,"p<.001",paste0("p=",p))),collapse="")
    text(9.5,5.5,labels=tmp.txt2,adj=c(1,0.5),cex=.75)
    text(9.5,5.5,labels=bquote(beta == .(b)%+-%.(s)),adj=c(1,0.5,cex=.75))


    ## same as above, but piped to a *.pdf
    pdf("tmp_output.pdf")
     plot(NULL,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10),xlab=NA,ylab=NA,xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
     tmp.txt <- paste(c(c," (n=",n,")\nslope = ",b,"±",s,"\n",ifelse(p==0,"p<.001",paste0("p=",p))),collapse="")
     text(9.5,9.5,labels=tmp.txt,adj=c(1,1),cex=.75)

     tmp.txt <- paste(c(c," (n=",n,")\n\U03B2  = ",b,"±",s,"\n",ifelse(p==0,"p<.001",paste0("p=",p))),collapse="")
     text(9.5,7.5,labels=tmp.txt,adj=c(1,1),cex=.75)

     tmp.txt2 <- paste(c(c," (n=",n,")\n\n",ifelse(p==0,"p<.001",paste0("p=",p))),collapse="")
     text(9.5,5.5,labels=tmp.txt2,adj=c(1,0.5),cex=.75)
     text(9.5,5.5,labels=bquote(beta == .(b)%+-%.(s)),adj=c(1,0.5,cex=.75))
    dev.off()
```

If you run this, it appears to work both inside of R and in the resulting *.pdf file.

As always, a more elegant (and sensible) solution would be much appreciated.